# how to type a custom callable type in Python

Tags: python, generics, mypy, typing, callable

I have a class called Foo:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.my_attr = "hi"
        self.callable = callable

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # call the wrapped in function
         return self.callable(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would like to type its instances (the `__call__` method and the `my_attr` attribute).

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Hm, I'm closing this as "not reproducible", because (besides missing `-> RV` in `__call__`. unimported `Callable` and missing `func` body) this [works](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=3c54039bad87c91dc0123c7c18cc3682). Please add more details to prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: I fixed my question. I answered the question myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Generics to solve the problem:

```
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Generic, Callable
P = ParamSpec("P")
RV = TypeVar("RV")

class Foo(Generic[P, RV]):
    def __init__(self, callable: Callable[P, RV]):
        self.my_attr = "hi"
        self.callable = callable

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RV:
         # call the wrapped in function
         return self.callable(*args, **kwargs)

def my_decorator(func: Callable[P, RV]) ->  Foo[P, RV]:
    return Foo(func)
```

Now these typing is valid:

```
@my_decorator
def func(a: int, b: str) -> str:
    raise NotImplementedError

s: str = func(1, "2") # valid typing for object cal
ss: str = func.my_attr # valid typing for attribute access
```